# Ncurses C program start itself in a terminal in xwindows

Tags: c, terminal, x11, ncurses

I've made a simple ncurses program, but it needs to be run from within a terminal to display anything.
If someone just double-clicks on it in a file manager window in X11, the program will not produce any output.
So my question is, how can I make it so that if someone double-clicks the binary, it'll automatically create a terminal window to run inside it? (Instead of that person having to open a terminal and having to enter commands to navigate to and execute it..)

Comment: I'm sure you can find a system command that does that. If there is none, there will be a desktop-specific command (like a special gnome way to discover the default terminal). And if there is none (unlikely), there still is the way of trying to find most popular terminal binaries in /bin, like /bin/xterm or /bin/gnome-terminal... just `fork` `execve` to it using your actual ncurses program as a command line parameter. no ? There is actually a system command on windows to start the default console, that is why i thought there could be one on linux as well.

Comment: If you have a file manager, it probably has a "Create a new link to application" command in its context menu. It may be called "shortcut" or "desktop label" or some other such thing. These terms all refer to the same thing.

In the creation dialog there are typically several tabs or "wizard steps", one of them should have a "run in terminal" check button.  Such a button may also be hidden behind an "Advanced options" dialog. Tick it, fill the rest of the info, and you are good to go.

Comment: But i don't believe its the essence of his question at all. how do you distribute that ? each people using his stuff will have to manually execute those steps themselves, doesn't sound that great of an installer.

Comment: @v.oddou `how do you distribute that?` You distribute that **exactly** like your OS distributes `vi`.

Comment: @v.oddou If you insist on distributing the launcher, you can. The format is standardized. See http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html

Comment: @n.m.: lol, well its not **me** who insists. But i have a strong feeling that OP's question is about that. So actually your idea/info here, will serve. (in my sense)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple bash shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e "your command"
```

Comment: this doesnt feel very right, first it supposes xterm is installed, it even supposes bash is installed (but that is acceptable). Then it also creates a non-well packaged application that has a binary and a launcher. it would be best packaged if the binary could execute the terminal window all by itself.

Comment: What about: /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator -e "your command" ? maybe embedded in the program.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a hack, but you could make an xmyapp like this, that runs myapp:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

   char *display = getenv("DISPLAY") ; 

   if(display){
       std::system("/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator -e <myapp>");
   } else {
       std::system("<myapp>");
   }      

   return 0;
}
```

Or in a single executable, like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   char *display = getenv("DISPLAY") ;
   std::string args = "";

   for(int i=1;i<argc;i++){
      args = argv[i];
      if(args == "--with-term") display = NULL;
   }

   if(display){
       std::system("/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator -e <myapp> --with-term");
       return 0;
   }
   //else
   //my app code

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have an /etc/alternatives/ folder, nor does locate find 'x-terminal-emulator'. Isn't there some generic, simply way to cause X to run the app in a terminal without me having to guess or test for all possible terminals which might be installed on the target system? Hard to believe.

Comment: X doesn't run app's, gnome,kde,xfce,etc does. Also a terminal is just another app there is no such thing as "default terminal" this all depends on whether you're running gnome/kde/etc. Sorry about the /etc/alternatives this seems to be Debian related. Which dist are you using?